# My vim can't print Chinese right on my mac?

Tags: encoding

only the vim app can't show the Chinese right. I have checked the encoding, fileencoding and fileencodings configs, all of them are utf-8 at the first.

[image: first is vim app, second is notepad of mac, third is vim in my iterm]

Comment: Could you explain what is in your screenshot? I guess the first image is gVim, the second one another graphical text editor and the third one is vim in a terminal? Also you might be interested in reading [`:h 'guifontset'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27guifontset%27).

Comment: @statox Thanks for your answer. But I remember some month ago it worked right and I never set anything about the `guifontset`.So I think there must be some other settings made the problem. And I diffed the recent changes of the .vimrc file, finally I fount `Plugin 'Lokaltog/vim-powerline'` made the problem. But I don't know why.

Comment: I add an issue on powerline github: https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/2018