# Chinese characters become unrecognizable overnight in Neovim

Tags: neovim, encoding

I typed a lot of Chinese characters in *Neovim* into a LaTeX file (.tex), and when I opened the file the next day all the characters became unrecognizable (everything looked great before I shut down my machine the first day): [image]

The file still works well, when I compile the .tex file into pdf everything was fine. I do can open the file with *gedit* to get all the correct Chinese characters and than paste them back to Neovim but that would be tedious.

This seems to be an encoding problem, I hope to get some insightful ideas about how to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you check `:verbose set encoding?`, and you might want to check `locale` in a terminal too.

Comment: `:verbose set encoding` gives`encoding=utf-8 Last set from ~/.config/nvim/init.vim line 28`, I set it explicitly in the config file before writing this file. Locale in terminal gives all the items `en_US.UTF-8`. I start to wonder whether this is a plugin problem (related to LaTeX) , as many other Chinese files stay fine up til now (mostly written in markdown). I use plugins `vimtex`, `coc-texlab` and `coc-vimtex`.

Comment: You could use our classic [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) post to narrow it down a bit. I really am not sure if the characters are supported by en-UTF8 locales (unless they are strictly UTF-8 *and* they were input/saved that way)

Comment: Mysteries solved, I set `fileencodings=utf-8` (beware the s) and things look well now. A similar question is [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20591/my-vim-cant-print-chinese-right-on-my-mac). This configuration seems to set vim to read a file using a specific encoding scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim has 4 configurations related to encoding: encoding, fileencoding, fileencoding**s**, and termencoding.  Encoding is what vim uses internally, fileencoding**s** sets the turn in which vim tries to figure out the current file encoding scheme, and the first successful scheme will be set as fileencoding. Termencoding is what is used when printing to screen (using terminal).

In my case, I used `set fileencodings=utf-8` to solve the problem.